# how to fix provlem table & select?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the function, it gives me back the space in front of the data.
Where I'm wrong.
Please yours if based on this example you can help me do that.
I want to return the data for correction from the delivery note table, but there is a problem with the space, how to solve it.

cod

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
Select your favorite fruit:
<table>
<tr>
<td>
1
</td>
<td>
orange
</td>
</td>
<td>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it</button>
</td>

</tr>
</table>

<select id="mySelect">
<option value="apple">Apple</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
<option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
<option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
</form>



<script>
function myFunction(td) {

selectedRow = td.parentElement.parentElement;
document.getElementById("mySelect").value= selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you're trying to do it from HTML, try to `trim()` excess spaces from the `.innerHTML` because HTML is not Space Sensitive, but JavaScript is:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").value = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML.trim();
//                                                                        ^^^^^^^
```

This will make it work. Snippet here:

```js
function myFunction(td) {
  selectedRow = td.parentElement.parentElement;
  document.getElementById("mySelect").value = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML.trim();
}
```

```html
<form>
  Select your favorite fruit:
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        orange
      </td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>
```